# Rendering Problems in Intellij 13.1.3,there is only API 20 in "Android version to use when rendering layouts in the IDE"

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I read this answer [Rendering issue for Android with Intellij 13.1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482649/rendering-issue-for-android-with-intellij-13-1-3) ,but there is only API 20,can not set lower version 
[image]

my project AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
package="com.example.myapp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have the other SDKs.
To download them, open the SDK manager from Android Studio, and download `Android 4.4.2 (API 19)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I did, I downloaded earlier SDK's but nothing new appeared this the drop down menu. I can change target android version in the project settings but this doesn't fix the layout problem.

I have only API 23 to chose from and nothing else.